# With the Visual Studio debugger, what's the best way to evaluate multiple function calls on one line?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Let's say I am using the debugger in Visual Studio on the following code:

```
if (method1() == method2())
{
 // do something
}
```

Is there a way to see the results of `method1()` and `method2()` without manually stepping into each one and going through the whole method?

Comment: you _could_ save the results into variables first. (which IMHO would be the cleaner code, anyway)

Comment: Set a breakpoint at all return statements of each method. Write the return value into a variable and compare the variables.

Comment: If the functions have no side effects, you could run them in the Immediate or the Watch window.

Comment: Or select e.g. "method1()" and right-click > QuickWatch.  As Klaus says, ideally they have no side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following steps to see the results of the method

1. Set breakpoints and start debugging.
   [image]
2. Right-click on the method and choose “Add Watch”
3. You can check the value of the method here
   [image]